# I am getting stale element reference while clicking on the option from UI-select dropdown

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I am getting stale element reference while  clicking on the option from UI-select dropdown.

below is the code for your reference. Plz kindly help me on this issue.

//Selecting the Origin from UI-Select list

```
this.select_sli_origin= function(origin)
   {   console.log(" origin value : " +origin);

       element(by.model(sli_locators.ori_sli_model)).click();

       browser.sleep(2000);

       element.all(by.repeater(sli_locators.ori_sli_repeater)).then(function (items) {
                  items.forEach(function (item) {

                item.getText().then(function (text) {
                    console.log("Service list :" + text);
                    if (text.substr(-3) == origin) {
                        item.click();
                    }
                });

            });
        });

       return this;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand, you need to filter a single item from the repeater for further clicking. You should not be using `forEach()` or `each()` here, you need [`filter()`](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter):

```
var items = element.all(by.repeater(sli_locators.ori_sli_repeater));
var desiredItem = items.filter(function (item) {
   return item.getText().then(function (text) {
       return text.substr(-3) === origin;
   });
}).first();
desiredItem.click();
```

FYI, the *Stale Element Reference Error* is very common when using Selenium. In your case it is thrown when calling `item.getText()` because the state of the page changed after the `item.click()` was issued on a previous iteration.